# Collapsing near-duplicates and adding difference as new column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame called people which describes unique employees. The thing is that the journey of job roles an employee has had is expressed by a new row for each new role, where all variables stay the same except for Job_history.

```
employee_ID <- c('1','1','2','2','2','3','4','4')
name <- c('Adam','Adam','Ben','Ben','Ben','Chris','Dan','Dan')
Job_role <- c('Manager','Manager', 'CSO', 'CSO', 'CSO','Manager', 'CTO', 'CTO')
Job_history <- c('Manager', 'Web designer', 'CSO', 'Graduate', 'Intern', '0', 'CTO', 'Manager')

people.data <- data.frame(employee_ID, name, Job_role, Job_history)

  employee_ID    name Job_role  Job_history
1           1    Adam  Manager      Manager
2           1    Adam  Manager Web designer
3           2     Ben      CSO          CSO
4           2     Ben      CSO     Graduate
5           2     Ben      CSO       Intern
6           3   Chris  Manager      Manager
7           4     Dan      CTO          CTO
8           4     Dan      CTO      Manager
```

To further process my data I need to collapse these duplicates while preserving the job history. I would like to put the Job_history values that are currently in rows into new columns, and not have the current job repeated in the Job_history column. To visualise, I want the data.frame to look like this:

```
  employee_ID    name Job_role  Job_history Job_history2 
1           1    Adam  Manager Web designer          N/A
2           2     Ben      CSO     Graduate       Intern      
3           3   Chris  Manager          N/A          N/A
4           4     Dan      CTO      Manager          N/A
```

How do I go about this please? I have tried using duplicate() or unique() but struggle to get the values into the new columns, and in the right order (bottom to top becomes left to right for each employee).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a new field in your data frame which will contain the future column name (Job_history1, Job_history2, etc). We assign a sequential number (1, 2, ...) to each record, grouping by employee_ID, so the sequential starts from 1 for each employee.

```
library(dplyr)

people.data <-
  people.data %>%
  group_by(employee_ID) %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(column_name = paste0("Job_history", seq)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(seq))

print(people.data)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  employee_ID name  Job_role Job_history  column_name 
  <fct>       <fct> <fct>    <fct>        <chr>       
1 1           Adam  Manager  Manager      Job_history1
2 1           Adam  Manager  Web designer Job_history2
3 2           Ben   CSO      CSO          Job_history1
4 2           Ben   CSO      Graduate     Job_history2
5 2           Ben   CSO      Intern       Job_history3
6 3           Chris Manager  0            Job_history1
7 4           Dan   CTO      CTO          Job_history1
8 4           Dan   CTO      Manager      Job_history2
```

Now all we need to do is to apply a pivot operation to transpose the values of desired fields onto new columns.

```
library(tidyr)

people.data <-
  people.data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column_name, values_from = Job_history)

print(people.data)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  employee_ID name  Job_role Job_history1 Job_history2 Job_history3
  <fct>       <fct> <fct>    <fct>        <fct>        <fct>       
1 1           Adam  Manager  Manager      Web designer NA          
2 2           Ben   CSO      CSO          Graduate     Intern      
3 3           Chris Manager  0            NA           NA          
4 4           Dan   CTO      CTO          Manager      NA
```

An interesting improvement occurs if you think an employee can have more 10 or more history entries. Because in that case, columns will be placed in alphabetical order: Job_history1, Job_history10, Job_history2, etc which is not what we want. So we need to use two digits instead to format the column names: Job_history01, Job_history02, etc. On an extreme case, we may even have more than 99 entries, so 3 digits would be necessary, and so on. We want to keep the number of digits to a minimum and yet make the solution scalable. What we must do is fetch the highest sequential number assigned and determine how many digits it will need.

```
# Scalable solution
people.data <- data.frame(employee_ID, name, Job_role, Job_history)

people.data <-
  people.data %>%
  group_by(employee_ID) %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

seq_digits <- nchar(as.character(max(people.data$seq)))

people.data <-
  people.data %>%
  mutate(column_name = sprintf("Job_history%0*d", seq_digits, seq)) %>%
  select(-c(seq))

people.data <-
  people.data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column_name, values_from = Job_history)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of columns you need to add its a good idea to automatically query the number of rows by name to find out how deep the job history is:

```
employee_ID <- c('1','1','2','2','2','3','4','4')
name <- c('Adam','Adam','Ben','Ben','Ben','Chris','Dan','Dan')
Job_role <- c('Manager','Manager', 'CSO', 'CSO', 'CSO','Manager', 'CTO', 'CTO')
Job_history <- c('Manager', 'Web designer', 'CSO', 'Graduate', 'Intern', '0', 'CTO', 'Manager')

people.data <- data.frame(employee_ID, name, Job_role, Job_history)

#install required packages  
install.packages("tidyquery")
library(tidyquery)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

#get maximum entries per name to automatically get the columns need to be attached
maxrowcount <- query(people.data, "Select count(*) as 'Number', name GROUP BY name")
maxrowcount <- max(maxrowcount$Number, na.rm = TRUE)
maxrowcount
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `dplyr` within `tidyverse`:

```
people.data %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Job"), names_to = "Job", names_prefix = "job", values_to = "role") %>% 
group_by(employee_ID, name) %>% 
mutate(rn = cumsum(role != lag(role, default = first(role))), roles = if_else(rn == 0, "role", paste0("history", rn))) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
select(-Job) %>% 
distinct() %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c("employee_ID", "name"), names_from = roles, names_prefix = "job_", values_from = role)
```

leading to:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  employee_ID name  job_role job_history1 job_history2 job_history3
  <fct>       <fct> <fct>    <fct>        <fct>        <fct>       
1 1           Adam  Manager  Web designer NA           NA          
2 2           Ben   CSO      Graduate     CSO          Intern      
3 3           Chris Manager  0            NA           NA          
4 4           Dan   CTO      Manager      NA           NA
```